# Iterate and group array of objects in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have the following MySQL table:

```
+----+----------+--------+------+
| id | brand    | model  | year |
+----+----------+--------+------+
| 1  | audi     | tt     | 2014 |
+----+----------+--------+------+
| 2  | audi     | a4     | 2015 |
+----+----------+--------+------+
| 3  | mercedes | aclass | 2014 |
+----+----------+--------+------+
| 4  | mercedes | cclass | 2017 |
+----+----------+--------+------+
```

I am using MYSQL in PHP and writing a query to get this data:

```
$carsQuery = SELECT * FROM cars_table ORDER BY model ASC;
```

After the query is executed I am using PHP to try an achieve the following JSON Object output:

```
{
    "car_models": [
        {
            "id": "audi",
            "name": "Audi",
            "cars": [
                {
                    "id": "1",
                    "model": "tt",
                    "year": "2014",
                    "brand": "audi"
                    },
                {
                    "id": "2",
                    "model": "a4",
                    "year": "2015",
                    "brand": "audi"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "mercedes",
            "name": "Mercedes",
            "cars": [
                {
                    "id": "3",
                    "model": "aclass",
                    "year": "2014",
                    "brand": "mercedes"
                    },
                    {
                    "id": "4",
                    "model": "cclass",
                    "year": "2017",
                    "brand": "mercedes"
                    }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The following snippet is the PHP code I am using to achieve this:

```
foreach($carsQuery as $carQuery){ 
        $cars[$carQuery->brand][] = $carQuery;
    }

return array( 
        'car_models' => $carQuery
        );
```

The result is being grouped however I cannot get to the point of adding the other fields in order to achieve the JSON object I want.

Comment: Did you choose that JSON structure or is it an external constraint? If the former then you might reconsider the structure. If the latter then you should align the sorting of the query output with the data hierarchy in your JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the other fields is mostly just a matter of defining them in the array you're building.

```
foreach ($carsQuery as $carQuery) {
    $cars[$carQuery->brand]['id'] = $carQuery->brand;
    $cars[$carQuery->brand]['name'] = ucfirst($carQuery->brand);
    $cars[$carQuery->brand]['cars'][] = $carQuery;
}
```

'id' and 'name' will be overwritten with the same value for multiple records of the same brand.

You may need to use some other approach than `ucfirst` to format the 'name' field, as some values may have different capitalization.

You should also use `array_values` to create your final array, in order to replace the string keys with numeric ones.

```
return array(
    'car_models' => array_values($cars)
);
```

That will ensure that car_models is an array of objects in your final JSON, rather than an object.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply, that worked perfectly fine. The only issue, the JSON output is not sorted how I want. How can I sort the objects with the brand name?

Comment: Add it to the order by clause in your query. `...ORDER BY brand, model` or actually, if you want it like your example, `brand, id`

Comment: I already order by brand, however the model in the car s array are not alphabetical

Comment: @Jojo I noticed that after I commented before. I edited the previous comment. With your example data, you should be able to get your example output with either `ORDER BY brand, id` or `ORDER BY brand, year`.